scrapy spider's speed is so slow
I am writing a scrapy spider for an e-commerce website, and have a limited time.
I just learned how to web-scrap and i know this code is not the most efficient; however, I cannot find a reason for this code to take 27 minutes.
class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "products"
    start_urls = ["there is link here"]

    def parse(self, response):
        selector1 = "ul[class='mobile-sub wsmenu-list']"
        selector2 = "li[class = 'wsshoplink-active'] div[class = 'wstitemright clearfix wstitemrightactive'] div[class = 'col-lg-12 col-md-12 clearfix'] ul li"
        categoryList = response.css(selector1)[0].css(selector2)

        for category in categoryList:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=category.css("li a::attr(href)").extract_first(),
                callback=self.parse_category_to_product,
            )

    def parse_category_to_product(self, response):
        product_links = response.css("#products a::attr(href)").extract()

        for eachlink in product_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=eachlink, callback=self.parse_main_item)

        next_page = response.css("link[rel='next']::attr(href)").extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_category_to_product)

    def parse_main_item(self, response):
        item = ProductScrapperItem()

        name = response.css("h1[class = 'product-h1']::text").extract_first()
        item["name"] = name

        itemdict = dict()
        itemdict["name"] = name

        with open("test03.json", "a") as f:  # Open in append mode
            json.dump(itemdict, f, indent=4)
            f.write(",\n")

        return item


I already took those settings out of comment in settings.py :
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 32
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 32
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 5.0
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False


scrapy bench

gives this:
2024-04-07 01:58:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2024-04-07 01:58:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2024-04-07 01:58:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 120 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:09 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:10 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:11 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:12 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:13 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 3 pages (at 60 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:14 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 3 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:15 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 4 pages (at 60 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 5 pages (at 60 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:17 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 29 pages (at 1440 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-07 01:58:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (closespider_timeout)
2024-04-07 01:58:18 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 18922,
 'downloader/request_count': 61,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 61,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 105029,
 'downloader/response_count': 61,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 61,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 10.472302,
 'finish_reason': 'closespider_timeout',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 6, 22, 58, 18, 14594, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'log_count/INFO': 20,
 'request_depth_max': 3,
 'response_received_count': 61,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 60,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 60,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1201,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1201,

tried to speed up scrapy spider, but it did not.
any help is priceless for me.

I don't think it's possible to suggest anything with the amount of the info provided.

what information should I provide further, I don't know. @wRAR

@serkanertas add the url

Create and open a JSON file once, and subsequently write to the already-opened file. This approach helps mitigate I/O-bound issues and marginally enhances performance.

@serkanertas depends on your expectations. If you want us to debug your code for you you need to provide actual code. If you want to ask specific questions about specific metrics you need to provide those metrics. If you want help with a specific problem you need to describe it.

@SIM I discovered I can just write "scrapy runspider <spider_path> -o products.json" to the terminal and scrapy does it automatically. However, it is still so slow that it takes roughly 35 minutes to finish scraping all the products.

@wRAR Especially on this topic, I don't think giving the link to the website is essential. The main problem is probably that I need to go to all products' web pages, and then request the HTML code since I fixed the problem about opening JSON file each loop. I think this little code cannot take roughly 35 minutes even if it will iterate so many times.
